# json content for authentication in lua

Tags: lua

I have a json containing the specified set of users. I want to access these json file for the authentication. Access the json in my action page `get.lua` .
Please help me to find a solution.

**json**

```
[
  {
    "username" : "ram"
  },
  {
    "username" : "rohan"
  }
]
```

**get.lua**

```lua
require "string"
require 'apache2'
function handle(r)
local POST, POSTMULTI = r:parsebody()
local name = POST['username']
r.content_type = "text/plain"
if( name == "aa") then
local file = io.open("/var/www/html/settings.txt", "w")
    if r.method == 'POST' then
r:puts("\n...The Log Detailsss...\n\n") 
        for k, v in pairs( POST,POSTMULTI ) do
          r:puts( string.format("%s: %s\n\n", k, v) )
file:write(string.format("%s: %s\n\n", k, v))
       end
    else
        -- use the ErrorDocument
        return 501
    end
file:close()
else
 r:puts( "Access Denied...!!" )
--r:escape_html("aa.html")
end
    return apache2.OK
end
```

Comment: And what is exactly the problem or the error?

Comment: the problem is i want to ensure that user with username from the json file should be logged in. All others have denied the access